# Unknown Source Exception when using addProtocolCommandListener with library org.apache.commons.net.telnet.TelnetClient

Tags: java, apache, telnet, apache-commons-net

I'm using the following library...

```
org.apache.commons.net.telnet.TelnetClient;
```

I have this piece of code which I am using to connect to a server.

```
import org.apache.commons.net.*;
import org.apache.commons.net.ProtocolCommandListener
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient
import org.apache.commons.net.telnet.TelnetClient;


String server = "some server";
String result = '';

//Create the telnet client and connect on port 43
TelnetClient telnetClient = new TelnetClient();
telnetClient.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(new PrintWriter(System.out)));
telnetClient.connect(server, 43);
```

When i get to the line with....

```
telnetClient.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(new PrintWriter(System.out)));
```

I get the following exception....

Caught: java.lang.NullPointerException
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:3140', transport: 'socket'
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.addProtocolCommandListener(SocketClient.java:772)
    at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient$addProtocolCommandListener.call(Unknown Source)

Anybody know why I might be getting this exception? 
If I remove the line I don't so the exception is this line. And if i use the FTPS client i do not have this problem with SFTP from the same library!

Hi, thanks for responding, here is a simple example of some supported clients in the library, i'm guessing maybe that whois and ftp client do not support the listner !?

```
   import org.apache.commons.net.*;
   import org.apache.commons.net.ProtocolCommandListener;
   import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
   import org.apache.commons.net.telnet.TelnetClient;
   import org.apache.commons.net.whois.WhoisClient;
   import java.io.PrintWriter;

   public class WhoisExample
   {
       public static void main(String args[])
       {
           try {
               WhoisClient whoisClient = new WhoisClient();
               whoisClient.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(new PrintWriter(System.out)));
           }
           catch(Exception e) {
               System.out.println("whois client exception" + e);
           }

           try {
               TelnetClient telnetClient = new TelnetClient();
               telnetClient.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(new PrintWriter(System.out)));
           }
           catch(Exception e) {
               System.out.println("telnet client exception" + e);
           }

           try {
               FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
               ftpClient.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(new PrintWriter(System.out)));

               System.out.println("no ftp client exception here !");
           }
           catch(Exception e)
           {
               System.out.println("ftp client exception" + e);
           }
       }
   }
```

Comment: Hi, i have a question: How are you running this code? Are you using the JRE or JDK? It seems that the mesage "Unkonw code" is show if you are running over JRE or with Ant and the debug parameter set to false. Changing that could give you more info. On the other hand, _NullPointerException_ should be indicating that telnetClient is null. Could you post full stack trace and/or complete actual code? Cheers

Comment: so I think the following code will show 3 different examples supported by the library....

Comment: which version of commons net is are you using?

Comment: Hi , I am using version 3.5

Answer (score 0):

I logged a bug with Apache commons net and it has been resolved as not a problem.

Basically .....'Some clients don't currently support the ProtocolCommand Listener.'

You can find out more from the following link....

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NET-608